# how to install pfa fonts in windows

Tags: windows, windows-7, fonts

I have extracted fonts from pdf but they have extension like

> font.pfa

how can i install those fonts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PFA stands for Printer Font Ascii. PFB stands for Printer Font Binary.

[Wikipedia on postscript fonts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript_fonts#Windows_support) suggests that Windows doesn't support PFA, but does support PFB.

So, try converting your PFA to PFB, perhaps using https://onlinefontconverter.com

Comment: So, how to install `pfb` font? `fontview.exe` tells it's not a valid file.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph Ages since I looked at this, but I don't remember anything unusual. Which version of Windows?